# Passing sum function matlab and add column wise sum

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, function-handle

Is it possible to pass the sum function and declare how to summarize the values? So column or row wise? Like I call the function without passing:

```
y = sum(x,2);
```

I want to call an Aggregation function like this, but operate in the rows:

```
Output = Aggregate(Input,@sum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a little on how `Aggregate` uses the function handle it's being passed, but the following should work

`Output = Aggregate(Input,@(x)sum(x,2));`

Comment: works for me, as I pass the function handle via an Input struct. that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To **apply the passed function along the second dimension**:

```
Aggregate = @(x,fun) fun(x,2);
```

As you see, this calls the passed function (`fun`) on the input (`x`) , with a fixed extra argument `2` to indicate the dimension along which the function will operate. This will work for any function that, like `sum`, accepts the dimension as a second argument.

Examples:

```
>> Aggregate([1 2; 3 4], @sum)
ans =
     3
     7
>> Aggregate([1 2; 3 4], @prod)
ans =
     2
    12
```

---

To **apply the passed function along a specified dimension**:

```
Aggregate = @(x,fun,dim) fun(x,dim);
```

Example:

```
>> Aggregate([1 2; 3 4], @sum, 2)
ans =
     3
     7
```

Comment: In the aggregate function, I do a lot of other calculations, and I want to pass the sum function as an input parameter, which I want to use in the aggregate function. The Aggregate function itself should not be the function to sum up my values.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what my code does, isn't it? See my examples above with the `sum` and `prod` functions passed as inputs

Comment: I understand your code in the way, that you define the `Aggregate` function in the Workspace and the `Aggregate` function does calculations with values and a function like `sum` or `prod`. But my Intention is to pass an input parameter (in my case `sum` function) to another function, which is defined in another script. In a part of the other function I want to use the input Parameter, the `sum` function, to make some calculations. The Aggregate function itself should not only return the sum or product of my given array. Therefore, solution `output = Aggregate(Input,@(x)sum(x,2)` works for me.